# Anaconda Private Repos

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

I am working for a X company and we want to upload private packages on the anaconda.cloud so that a small team of the company can install these with `conda`.

Does anyone know what the process is to be able to upload private packages?

The company has bought few commercial-editions and I was assigned to an Organization inside anaconda.nucleus but I don't know if it possible to upload private packages or how should I do it.

Are there any required rights on the Organization before doing so?

Please let me know your thoughts if ever worked with private packages on Anaconda.

Comment: How is it off-topic? I asked for some technical knowledge as anaconda docs aren't helpful enough.. Wouldn't have asked it if I could find help somewhere else... I know the rules. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is (to my knowledge) no authentication built into `conda` and I have never heard of private repositories hosted on anaconda.org. There are some other options though that I can think of:

- Create a folder on a network drive that is organized and indexed like a [local repo](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html) which you can then serve as a channel
- Since you mention that your company is spending money on proprietary anaconda software, take a look at the [Anaconda Enterprise Repository](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/):

> Anaconda Enterprise 4 Repository is an enterprise server on your network or your private cloud where open source and **proprietary packages** may be stored.

This is no place to discuss pros and Cons between the different methods available to you and I am not a sales rep or in any other way associated with Continuum. Best would be to have your IT department/your team decide which option meets your needs and security requirements

Comment: Yes there it is an login option for `anaconda-client` and packages can be uploaded privately to anaconda.org ...

Comment: Thus uploading private packages requires a paid subscription, I activated one for myself, but still unable to upload yet or I don't know how